# image processing: correct image to some reference red and blue components of white balance

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, camera

The drivers of a camera I use allows to set the white balance red and blue components (integer between 0 and 100).

With this camera, I took some darkframes (reference images taken when no light going in the camera) with the red and blue components fixed at some reference values.

Now I have some pictures taken by the same camera, but using other (known) values for the red and blue components. I would like to correct them to the reference values (before subtracting one of the darkframes).

All pictures taken (including the darkframes) are raw 16 bits 1d numpy array (no debayering).

Comment: white balance is _factors_ on the linear sensor values, not offsets on them. darkfield frames only help set noise levels (offsets), not white balance/color temperature.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz it seems to me (I am unsure): the camera's sensor get lights with offsets (noise), then apply some factors (white balance) to each color, then the image is returned. So if I want to substract a darkframe to an image (i.e. removing the offsets), I have first to correct it, i.e. "reverting" the factors that were applied to the image before applying the factors that were applied to the darkframe. Anything I get wrong ?

Comment: well yes, if your image is a processed version, you'd have to undo the processing. if you have the raw values, then you don't have to undo anything. -- camera processing is commonly more complex than just this simple "gamma(ax+b)" calculation. check out https://www.eecs.yorku.ca/~mbrown/ICCV19_Tutorial_MSBrown.pdf